# For let, not incrementing if there is a same item in array

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

I'm trying to increment an item in my mongodb using find $in array, but when there is a same item in an array for example `['apple','apple']` it should increment twice but for my case, it only increment once, look at my code:

```
 var newValue = 1;
 var newSerialcode = req.body.serialCode; 
 var newBloodgroup = req.body.blood_group; 
 var newGetbloodcomponent = req.body.blood_component; 

 Bloodinventory.find({ blood_component : { $in : newGetbloodcomponent} ,blood_group: { $in :newBloodgroup},chapter: { $in: [id] }}, function(err, bloodinventoryDocs) {

            for(let bloodinventory of bloodinventoryDocs) {
                bloodinventory.num_stock = bloodinventory.num_stock + newValue ;                        
                bloodinventory.save(function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err); 
                    } else {
                        console.log('success'); 
                    }
                });
            }  
        });
```

Comment: What array should have duplicated values? is it `bloodinventoryDocs`? which is return value of the `find()` query?

Comment: Assuming newGetbloodcomponent has a duplicate values like ['whole blood','whole blood']

Comment: I think you probably misunderstood what `$in` is for. Let me explain how your query would work in human language, you are finding all blood inventories that blood_component is in newGetbloodcomponent, blood_group is in newBloodgroup and chapter is in id. So your query will return same result even if you have duplicated value in your array.

Comment: You should show some sample documents, the arguments you are using for the query and what you expect to happen as a result. As stated earlier, simply supplying a value "twice" within an `$in` does not cause it to fetch the matching document "twice". In fact, MongoDB will actually "strip the duplicates" in the query before processing. As it should.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been a while, but this might still help you (or maybe someone else), so...

Perhaps you can try this:

```
var newValue = 1;
var newSerialcode = req.body.serialCode; 
var newBloodgroup = req.body.blood_group; 
var newGetbloodcomponent = req.body.blood_component; 

Bloodinventory.find({ blood_component : { $in : newGetbloodcomponent} ,blood_group: { $in :newBloodgroup},chapter: { $in: [id] }}, function(err, bloodinventoryDocs) {

    for(let bloodinventory of bloodinventoryDocs) {
        // === change starts here === //
            // filter into a new array all the places where this particular blood component occurs
            let all_occurences = newGetbloodcomponent.filter(function(b){
                return b === bloodinventory.blood_component;
            });

            // to avoid incurring unnecessary processing and/or database costs, only continue if an occurence was actually found
            if(all_occurences.length > 0){
                // increment it by that amount (which will be the number of items filtered into the array)
                bloodinventory.num_stock = bloodinventory.num_stock + all_occurences.length;
                // ^^ you could also write this as 'bloodinventory.num_stock += all_occurences.length;'
            
                bloodinventory.save(function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err); 
                    } else {
                        console.log('success'); 
                    }
                });
            };
        // === change ends here === //
    }  
});
```